# Why does HTTPSConnection.request() sometimes not work with file objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7

[HTTPConnection.request() documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.request) says:

> If the body argument is present, it should be a string of data to send after the headers are finished. Alternatively, it may be an open file object, in which case the contents of the file is sent; this file object should support fileno() and read() methods.

So this usually works:

```
import httplib
import os

f = open('data.dat', 'rb')
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('localhost', 8000)
conn.request("PUT", "/", f, {
    "Content-Length": os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size,
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
})
```

But if `data.dat` is larger than ~5.5MB it stops working:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 81, in <module>
    conn.request("PUT", "/", f, {
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1057, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1097, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 901, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 870, in send
    self.sock.sendall(datablock)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 743, in sendall
    v = self.send(data[count:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 709, in send
    v = self._sslobj.write(data)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

However it keeps working if the argument `f` is replaced by `f.read()`!

Comment: Sounds like a server issue, not a client one. The server, as the error message indicates, is closing the connection, for whatever reason (upload limit reached maybe?)

Comment: But why does it work with `f.read()`? The same amount of data gets uploaded in that case.